# How to fix Undefined variable: image in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with Laravel 5.6 and in my application I have a category create form in the form.blade.php file...

```
@if(isset($image))
    <form method="PUT" action="http://localhost:8000/update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
@else
   <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/create" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="1LLYc0D1spmVSFMboLDjGM9MR4O5APVwng7giejx">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
@endif

            <div class="form-group row required">
                <label for="description" class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-lg-2">Description</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" autofocus placeholder="Description" name="description" type="text" id="description" value="{{$image->categoryname}}">
                </div> 
            </div>
```

I have both new category create form and edit form in the above blade file.

this is my CategoryController

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $images = Category::find($id);

    return view('categories.form')->withImages($images);
}
```

My edit form is working fine but when I click new Category create button it is generating following error

> Undefined variable: image (View: C:\Users\Nalaka\Desktop\acxian\resources\views\categories\form.blade.php)

Comment: could it be you refer to `$image` instead of `$images`?

Comment: both are not working

Comment: right, well after `$images = Category::find($id);` put `var_dump($images); exit;` if there is no result, there's your problem!

Comment: yes there is no result it is same error here

Comment: You are doing `{{$image->categoryname}}` regardless of whether `$image` is set or not.  Maybe put an if/else around that part too.

Comment: @PatrickQ how can I do it?

Comment: Just like you're doing at the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not sure I've seen this method `withImage` inside of `Laravel`, I would suggest you try with just `with`, like this:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $image = Category::find($id);

    return view('categories.form')->with(['image' => $image]);
}
```

If that doesn't work, then you need to include `if statement` for the `image description` too, because you have `{{ $image->categoryname }}` and you are not checking for it's existence at that point

EDIT: To envelop this into an `if else` statement, you can use ternary operator for it, like this:

`{{ isset($image) ? $image->categoryname : '' }}`

Comment: how can I add if/else statement here

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: For PHP 7+, you could also use `{{ $image->categoryname ?? '' }}` .